# Run executable in the same folder via PowerShell

Tags: powershell

I have a PowerShell script from which I want to run an executable in the same folder:

**RunTests.ps1**

```
.\nunitlite-runner.exe
```

When I right click the script in the Explorer and choose **Execute with Powershell** I get the following error:

```
Die Benennung ".\nunitlite-runner.exe" wurde nicht als Name eines Cmdlet, einer
Funktion, einer Skriptdatei oder eines ausführbaren Programms erkannt. Überprüfen
Sie die Schreibweise des Namens, oder ob der Pfad korrekt ist (sofern enthalten),
und wiederholen Sie den Vorgang.
Bei C:\Users\Test\Desktop\MyScripts\RunTests.ps1: 5 Zeichen:23
+ .\nunitlite-runner.exe <<<<
    + CategoryInfo          : ObjectNotFound: (.\nunitlite-runner.exe:String)    [], CommandNotFoundException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : CommandNotFoundException
```

Which basically translates to:

> The name ". \nunitlite-runner. exe" was not specified as the name of a
>   cmdlet, a  function, a script file or an executable program. checking
>   enter the spelling of the name or whether the path is correct (if it
>   contains) and repeat the procedure.

Comment: `& '.\nunitlite-runner.exe'`?

Comment: Did you try `$PSScriptRoot\nunitlite-runner.exe` ?  ....  or any other way to determine where the script is actually located ...

Comment: Are you running the script as Admin?  When you run as admin it defaults the location as the system32 directory.

For example I have a script that has the following code at the start:

`if (!([Security.Principal.WindowsPrincipal][Security.Principal.WindowsIdentity]::GetCurrent()).IsInRole([Security.Principal.WindowsBuiltInRole] "Administrator")) { Start-Process powershell.exe "-NoProfile -ExecutionPolicy Bypass -File `"$PSCommandPath`"" -Verb RunAs; exit }`

So even if I right click run with powershell it will run it as admin.

Answer (score 0):

OK, seems I have found the answer. The problem is not with Powershell or the script. Instead it's with Free Commander.

When I run the script via the context menu, Free Commander seems to not set the working directory correctly (thus the executable is not found). When I run the script via double click, it works just fine.

Comment: The correct solution to your problem is to use the actual script path instead of the working directory, as [Olaf suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48397981/run-executable-in-the-same-folder-via-powershell#comment83784302_48397981): `$PSScriptRoot\nunitlite-runner.exe` or `& "$PSScriptRoot\nunitlite-runner.exe"`.

Comment: Don't assume your scripts will be run with the current directory set to the one containing the script.  That's only true if you run them via double-clicking from Explorer. Otherwise, the cwd could be anywhere.